# Laravel ORM get frequency of each row and plug it back into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I can get the frequency of a row quite easily like this:

```
$urls = URL::select('url',DB::raw('count(*) as frequency'))
        ->groupBy('url')
        ->get();
```

and then getting the frequency value from each row in the query, but what if I wanted to plug the frequency back into the table? For example, my table has these values:

Frequency, url, id

How would I create a function to run through the table and update each row with its frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* be accomplished easier (and faster) with a straight query instead of using the query builder. I'm sure there is a way to do it the "Laravel Way", but this should work equally as well (assuming my query is correct):

```
$query = "UPDATE urls u1 SET u1.frequency = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM urls u2 WHERE u1.url = u2.url GROUP BY u2.url
)";

DB::update($query);
```

If you really wanted to do it one at a time in a more Laravel-esque approach, I suppose you could do something like:

```
$urls = Url::all();
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $url->frequency = (int) DB::table('urls')->where('url', '=', $url->url)->count();
    $url->save();
}
```

Comment: Thx for the fast response, I used your raw query and it worked after I changed (FROM urls u2) to (FROM (SELECT * FROM unknown_tags) u2).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know the specifics of your database. Glad it worked!